# Checking if the checkbox is checked or not in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a registration form where I gave a checkbox for the terms and conditions. I want to check if the checkbox is checked or not. If it is not checked I want to display a message in the paragraph tag I gave below it

I've given this code inside a function made with JQuery which is called when I click a button in the form.
I've tried a lot of things from the internet from stackoverflow, gfg, youtube but nothing is working. It's not even entering the if condition.
The commented function in the end is working though but I want it to work when the button is clicked

```js
function reset() {
  document.querySelector(".forms").reset();
}
// $(".fn, .un, .em, .pas, .con").hide();
$(".reg").click(function() {
  var fname = $("#fname").val();
  if (fname === "") {
    $("#fname").css("border", "2px solid red");
    $(".fn").html("Fullname is required");
  }
  var uname = $("#uname").val();
  if (uname === "") {
    $("#uname").css("border", "2px solid red");
    $(".un").html("Username is required");
  }
  var email = $("#em").val();
  if (email === "") {
    $("#em").css("border", "2px solid red");
    $(".em").html("Email is required");
  }
  var pass = $("#pass").val();
  if (pass.length < 8) {
    $("#pass").css("border", "2px solid red");
    $(".pas").html("Password must be atleast 8 characters long");
  }
  var check = $("#check").val();
  if (check.equals(pass)) {
    $("#check").css("border", "2px solid red");
    $(".con").html("Passwords don't match");
  }
  var tac = $("#tcs").prop("checked");
  if (!tac) {
    $(".tac").text("You should agree to the terms and conditions");
  }
});
$("input").focus(function() {
  $(":text, :password").css("border", "0.2px solid grey");
  $(":text, :password").css("border-bottom", "3px solid black");
  $("#em").css("border", "0.2px solid grey");
  $("#em").css("border-bottom", "3px solid black");
  $("p").empty();
});
// document.getElementsByClassName("tc").checked;


// function isChecked(){
//     if(!document.getElementById("tcs").checked){
//         // console.log("Hi");
//         $(".tac").html("You must agree to the terms and conditions to continue");
//     }
//     else{
//         // console.log("Bruh");
//         $(".tac").empty();
//     }
// }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="tcs">
<label for="tcs">I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
<p class="tac"></p>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1):

You should check the status of the checkbox input on the change event so it will be called every time the user makes any changes to that checkbox.
Here, is the example code that might meet your requirements.

You can call on the submit button as well to ensure the final state of the checkbox before proceeding further.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function my_fun(){
      var ckb_status = $("#tcs").prop('checked');
        if (!ckb_status) {
            $('.tac').html("You should agree to the terms and conditions");
        }
        else{
          $('.tac').html("");
        }
    }
    
    $("#tcs").change(my_fun);
    $("#sub").click(my_fun);
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id = "tcs">
    <label for="tcs">I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
    <p class = "tac"></p>
    <input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: I vote this down because it is not useful to check it is checked on change but instead should be done on submit

Comment: I tried my best to make changes to the code on my system, so where does the ChatGPT come into the picture???

Comment: As the given issue code doesn't contain any submit button that's why I included both the eventListeners to make it work for both with or without submit button.